# Laravel: Sum column based on relationship condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Let's say we have two tables:

#### Payments

| id | reason_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 1 | 30 |

#### Payment Reasons

| id | title | is_discount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Payment for something | 0 |
| 2 | Discount for something | 1 |

I'd like to query `payments` table and `sum amount` column based on its relationship `payment_reasons.is_discount` value:

| total_received | total_discounted |
| --- | --- |
| 130 | 10 |

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data in one db-request, I don't think there is a clean laravel-way to solve this. I've been trying out some raw mysql to get it into a working query and it would look like this:

```
select 
       sum(if(pr.is_discount = 0, p.amount, 0)) as total_received, 
       sum(if(pr.is_discount = 1, p.amount, 0)) as total_discounted 
from payments p
join payment_reasons pr on pr.id = p.reason_id
```

The `if` statement will render if discount needs to be used per row and the sum wil simply sum all the end-results together.

Doing this in laravel with a model does not really make sence, since there are no fields in the result which your model could use anyway. In this case, using [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent) would be more (unmaintainable) code than a simple [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries):

```
$data = DB::select('
    select 
           sum(if(pr.is_discount = 0, p.amount, 0)) as total_received, 
           sum(if(pr.is_discount = 1, p.amount, 0)) as total_discounted 
    from payments p
    join payment_reasons pr on pr.id = p.reason_id
')
```

If you don't mind doing multiple queries to fetch the data, models make more sense:

```
$totalReceived = Payment
    ::whereHas('paymentReason', fn($q) => $q->where('is_discount', 0))
    ->sum('amount');

$totalDiscounted = Payment
    ::whereHas('paymentReason', fn($q) => $q->where('is_discount', 1))
    ->sum('amount');
```

Please note that this example will perform 4 queries, 2 on payments, and 2 on payment_reasons

Comment: Thank you for your input. I guess it makes sense to drop eloquent in this situation. Your second example is what I had before, but it's just extremely unoptimized.